# Reload MainActivity after navigating with Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I need assistance getting my MainActivity to reload to reflect when a user logs in.

My MainActivity is as such:

```
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        if (session.getPerms().equals("mod") || session.getPerms().equals("dev") || session.getPerms().equals("admin")){
            Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
            nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_queue).setVisible(true);
        }else{
            Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
            nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_queue).setVisible(false);
        }

        if(session.getLogInState()){
            Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
            nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_login).setVisible(false);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_login) {
            Intent login = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(login);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_queue) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ModQueue.class));

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }
}
```

My Login Activity (or the part that matters more accurately):

```
if (conPassword.equals(secPassword)) {
                session.setLogInState(true);
                session.setEmail(conEmail); ;
                session.setPerms(perms);
                session.setFirst(first);
                session.setLast(last);
                rs.close(); //if a ResultSet was returned
                stmt.close(); //Close Statement
                con.close();
                System.out.println("Logged in");
                System.out.println(session.getPerms());
                Intent main = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(main);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Unable to Login");
            }
```

So the issue is when i go back to my MainActivity it has not updated and so it does not see that it is now logged in.

I need my MainActivity to show that i ma logged in so that it will show the appropriate options based on Permissions as well as hide the login option as it is already logged in.

edit:
Here is my Session Management class

```
    public class SessionManagement {
    private boolean LoggedIn = false;
    private String perms = "Guest";
    private String email;
    private String first;
    private String last;


    public boolean getLogInState(){ return LoggedIn; }

    public void setLogInState(Boolean Logged){ LoggedIn = Logged; }

    public String getPerms(){ return perms; }

    public void setPerms(String newPerms){ perms = newPerms; }

    public String getEmail(){ return email;}

    public void setEmail(String newEmail){ email = newEmail; }

    public String getFirst(){ return first;}

    public void setFirst(String newFirst){ first = newFirst; }

    public String getLast (){ return last;}

    public void setLast (String newLast){ last = newLast;}

}
```

Comment: How do you pass session between two activities?

Comment: Where does the login itself actually happen?  On a server, or on your phone?

Comment: @Maciej I have a separate class that houses local variables, such as a book for Logged in as well as strings for first, last, email, perms. As you can see called as get/setEmail, Perms etc

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the login is through a SQL db on a remote server using the MySQL connector.

Comment: @EzekielHammond is the session class a singleton?

Comment: Well how does the activity sync up with the server?  Is the correct post-login state being passed to your app?  Your refresh code should be working AFAIK.

Comment: @Maciej no it is not. I have added my session management class to the post

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen post login there is no communication to the server. The login takes the username, passed it to the connector, connector gets the password, if it matches the entered password it then gets the rest of the data and assign it to the variables in the session management class, then navigates to the mainactivity which is not seeing the updated information.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't see the problem.  You need to find out whether your main activity is in a logged in state or not somehow.  Either by synching with a server or by using state in your app, e.g. preferences or intent data.  I vote for using the server.

Comment: Just in case, there exists a [`Activity.recreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) method.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so when the login completes it changes Boolean LoggedIn in the session management class.

Mainactivity is not getting the updated variable data after the login. It should see LoggedIn as True after it logs in, and should see perms as whatever the perms are supposed to be. In my case Admin, but it just sees the default perms

Comment: @azizbekian I have tried that as well. No luck

Comment: I get it now.  What you're doing isn't working, a singleton might work, but in any case I think that best practice would be to check login status with each action in every activity.  A malicious user might try to hack your app and spoof it into thinking that the user is logged in.  This is my vote.

Comment: I think best practice would be if you set and get all value in SharedPreferences or as @TimBiegeleisen suggestion make the class singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when Activity is finished , `session` as a reference is destroyed, so all data in that object will be lost,
the new activity will create a new `session` which will be empty (default values)

what you need to do is use a singleton or use a `public static` variables in `SessionManagement`  and access them directly.

```
public class SessionManagement {
    public static boolean LoggedIn = false;
    public static String perms = "Guest";
    public static String email;
    public static String first;
    public static String last; ...
```

and in your Login activity:

```
if (conPassword.equals(secPassword)) {
   SessionManagement.LoggedIn = true;
   SessionManagement.perms =perms; ....
```

Also in MainActivity access the variables directly to check them,

```
if (SessionManagement.perms.equals("mod") ...
```

if you want to keep your variables private you can still use `private static` for variables and `public static` for the setters/getters this way it will work too, and you will keep your variables private

you can use like this:

```
SessionManagement.setPerms(...);
```

Comment: I thought it was best practice to not open your variables to public but have modifer methods instead?

Comment: it depends on the case, thats why i told you, you can use singleton, it will maintain the setters/getters , however if in your app, you know there will be no extra logic to do when setting or getting a value, ex, in setting you may update/set other values when setting `email`, and on getters like if a value is null, return empty string instead, or if you do some kind of validation or conversion when setting a value ... if not then just use the static variables. i think it would be OK

Comment: that makes sense. I will try in the morning thank you!

Comment: @EzekielHammond if you want, you can still use `private static` for variables and public static for the setters/getters this way it will work too, and you will keep your variables private

Answer (score 2):

So you have to create a Singleton class or create Session class as Parcelable to be able to pass it in a bundle.

## Singleton

You just keep the session in the memory. When the app is cleared, session also will be cleared out from memory.

#### Session

```
public class Session {
    public boolean isLoggedIn;
}
```

#### SessionInjector

```
public class SessionInjector {

private static Session session;

public static Session getSession() {
    if (session == null) {
        session = new Session();
    }
    return session;
}
}
```

### First Approach

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (!SessionInjector.getSession().isLoggedIn) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
    } else {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Logged In!");
    }
}

}
```

#### LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    SessionInjector.getSession().isLoggedIn = true;

    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}

}
```

### Second Approach

Start activity for result. This is perfect example for such occasions instead of finishing the activities and then restarting the same one. You just need to react to changes made.

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final static int LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE = 44;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (!SessionInjector.getSession().isLoggedIn) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class), LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Logged In!");
        }
    }
}

}
```

#### LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    SessionInjector.getSession().isLoggedIn = true;

    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}

}
```